# Not able to launch a specific app in Windows 8, stuck at splash screen

Tags: windows-8

The local app we have written is not launching in a specific Windows 8 machine only the splash screen appears.

The APP constructor itself is not called.

Note: 
This app works in other machines.
We upgraded the OS to 8.1 as well as disabled the antivirus as well.